# Is there any automation format for printing and data recording simultaneously

Tags: microsoft-office

I need to issue thousands of certificates over the years. Those certificates are uniform in formats just the name, address and several couple things vary for person to person. Now I am doing it in Microsoft word by copying previous certificate and changing this copy by new person data. By this process Microsoft word file is expanding day by day though most of it redundant and just the person data is unique.I need to keep tracks of these persons data for this reason I also keeping garbage alongwith.

Now is there any way that I need to input ONLY person data and the backend boilerplate would be same. After all certificate will be produced and the associated person data also will be saved in a database sort of things.

Comment: Mail Merge is your friend

Comment: [Use mail merge to create and send bulk mail, labels, and envelopes](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-mail-merge-to-create-and-send-bulk-mail-labels-and-envelopes-f488ed5b-b849-4c11-9cff-932c49474705)